# Oracle 10g Week number

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

The following query returns week no. 53, i think 02-Jan-2017 is start of week 1 of the year 2017.

```
SELECT TRUNC(CL_DT, 'IW') AS WK_STARTDATE,
       TRUNC(CL_DT, 'IW') + 6 AS WK_ENDDATE,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('02-JAN-17', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'IW') AS WK_WEEKNO,
       CL_DT,
       TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY')
  FROM PM_CALENDAR
 WHERE CL_DT = TO_DATE('02-JAN-17', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Please advice what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Correct, `2017-01-02` is in ISO week 1. But `0017-01-02` was in ISO week 53:

```
TO_DATE('02-JAN-17', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

It would have been better, had Oracle issued a format error, but well, the number 17 equals 0017 of course :-)

You should never rely on language settings anyway when converting strings to date (`'JAN'` is certainly not a valid month in every language you could set). You can specify a parameter in `TO_CHAR` for this. And `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY')` is just horrible. Here you even convert `SYSDATE` to string implicitely according to the default format in your system/session, which you then take for granted to be `'DD-MON-YY'` and you convert it back.

Better use ISO date literals instead (i.e. not work with strings and conversions at all):

```
date'2017-01-02'
```

Here is the corrected query:

```
SELECT TRUNC(CL_DT, 'IW') AS WK_STARTDATE,
       TRUNC(CL_DT, 'IW') + 6 AS WK_ENDDATE,
       TO_CHAR(DATE '2017-01-02', 'IW') AS WK_WEEKNO,
       CL_DT
  FROM PM_CALENDAR
 WHERE CL_DT = DATE '2017-01-02';
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice, and it solved my problem